# JS modal not working on every row

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony, bootstrap-modal

i cant really figure it out, why my javascript is not working on every table row.

Table code:

```
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    {# sorting of properties based on query components #}
    <th{% if pagination.isSorted( 'a.tytul') %} class="sorted" {% endif %}>{{ knp_pagination_sortable(pagination, 'Tytuł', 'a.tytul') }}</th>
      <th>{{ knp_pagination_sortable(pagination, 'Kategoria', 'a.kategoria') }}</th>
      <th>{{ knp_pagination_sortable(pagination, 'Cena ^', 'a.cena', {'direction': 'asc'})}}{{ knp_pagination_sortable(pagination, 'v', 'a.cena', {'direction': 'desc'})}}</th>
  </tr>

  {# table body #} {% for oferta in pagination %}
  <tr {% if loop.index is odd %}class="color" {% endif %}>
    <td><a href="{{ path('_oferta', {'idOferty' : oferta.idOferty}) }}"> {{ oferta.tytul }}</a>
    </td>
    <td>{{ oferta.kategoria }}</td>
    <td>{{ oferta.cena }}zł/miesiąc</td>
    <td>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Opcje <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></span> Zmień</a>
          </li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#" id="confirm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Usuń</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
{# display navigation #}
<div class="navigation col-sm-offset-11">
  {{ knp_pagination_render(pagination) }}
</div>
```

And the javascript:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#confirm").click(function(){
            $("#myModal").modal();
        });
    });
</script>
```

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you reference an item by ID you will only return the 1st object that matches.

If you want to target all items with the id of "confirm" although you should probably add another selector you can use the attribute selector.

**Your Example:** (Only 1st item works)

https://jsfiddle.net/SeanWessell/y7cg56bj/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("[id='confirm']").click(function(){
        $("#myModal").modal();
    });
});
```

**Attribute selector example:**

https://jsfiddle.net/SeanWessell/k8uqvd16/

https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

**OR** since you know there is a parent of tr you can add the tr to the selector before id and it will check each tr and find the 1st element with the id confirm.

```
$("tr #confirm").click(function(){
  $("#myModal").modal();
});
```

Comment: It works! Thanks man. Im learning lot of stuff every day cuz of guys like you :) Really appreciate!